How to resolve Heroku H10 'App crashed' error on deploying an Express app?
I'm deploying an Express.js application to Heroku, but I'm encountering a persistent H10 - App crashed error that I can't seem to resolve. Below are the relevant details and logs from Heroku:
Error Logs from Heroku:
2022-07-10T14:28:53.606628+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2022-07-10T14:28:53.703267+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2022-07-10T14:40:41.758300+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=HEAD path="/api/v3/rate_limit" host=pomoworki.herokuapp.com request_id=c0d582d4-7781-4db6-af9b-706f2050de41 fwd="181.56.0.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2022-07-10T14:40:47.486286+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=pomoworki.herokuapp.com request_id=2a00d7e4-316f-40ba-8218-a6d40df6cf29 fwd="181.56.0.86" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https

Server Setup:
Here's the basic setup of my server.js that might be relevant:

const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const connectDB = require('./config/db');

const app = express();
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    app.use(morgan('dev'));
}

app.use(cors());
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${process.env.PORT}`));


Procfile:
web: node server.js

I suspect the issue might be related to how I've configured the server or the database connection, but I can't pinpoint the exact cause. I've ensured that my Procfile is correctly pointing to server.js. What could be causing this issue and how can I resolve it?
Thank you for any help or guidance you can provide!

The error is very clear in that message: "Invalid ELF header". So fix that perhaps? Maybe one of these will help.

How can I do that?

It looks like you're copying your local environment (including node_modules) verbatim to Heroku while the platforms (local and Heroku) don't match. If possible, run npm install on Heroku instead of copying.
